# Implementing Java Objects as serializable when transferred in webServices as JSON

Tags: java, json, web-services, serialization

I am building a webService over jersey which uses Jackson for serializing Objects into JSON.
Since My objects are transferred as JSON over network, do I have to implement serialization explicitly as `public class MyObject implements serializable` or Jackson will do that for me?

Comment: Did you try both ways?

Comment: No, since object are transferred as json which are serialized by Jackson(as I believe)

Comment: Do you want us to try?

Comment: well, you can try that and tell me the results :)

Comment: Please try for yourself, don't believe. It is *your* question.

Comment: so how can I check the difference? like reading bits and bytes from network card?

Comment: @LutzHorn I have a simple question here, As i am not saving my objects anywhere in files. I am transferring them over network as JSON. So what may be the signification of implementing serializable on classes here?